# How to connect sql server from docker container which is hosted on different Server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am going to move my legacy stuff from traditional architecture to docker containers. I have Asp.net MVC application which talk to sql server in different server. Please suggest me how to configure my dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

I have added this file by visual studio.

And my .yml file would be:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  securemarkerapplication:
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? What kind of configuration are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special for Docker in this case at all.  However you'd configure the database in your non-Docker application, you'd do the same thing in Docker.  You might need to do Docker-specific things to set environment variables or inject a configuration file but those don't go in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Can you please send me some sample snippet where i can refer that things in my traditional app ?